Regarding the problem when performing SVM from kernel matrix with R's kernlab
The results are different depending on whether performing SVM from the explanatory variables or from the kernel matrix. I don't understand why there would be such a difference.
data(spam)
index <- sample(1:dim(spam)[1])
spamtrain <- spam[index[1:2000],]
spxx <- as.matrix(spamtrain[, 1:57])
stype <- spamtrain$type
spam.svm <- ksvm(spxx, stype, kernel="rbfdot", kpar=list(sigma=0.05), C=5, cross=3, scale=T)
error(spam.svm)  # 0.014
cross(spam.svm)  # 0.07649404
rbf <- rbfdot(sigma=0.05)
Kspam <- kernelMatrix(rbf, scale(spxx))
spam2.svm <- ksvm(Kspam, stype, C=5, cross=3)
error(spam2.svm)  # 0.145
cross(spam2.svm)  # 0.1175433

I want to know how to match the results of SVM from the kernel matrix and SVM from explanatory variables.

Then read the docs.
